# can't edit Boolean field on django model when it is link with another field from the same model within this logic scoop?

Tags: django, django-models, logic

I am working on django v4.* and I came cross a point where I need to make field `publish_date` to be auto populated when `is_published is ticked`

```
import datetime
class Article(models.Model):
     .......
     is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     publish_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
     .......
     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_published:
           self.publish_date = datetime.datetime.now()
           super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

this did the trick but the problem that I can not edit the `is_published` field anymore,
when I tick it (make it true) it stay true even if I try to change it to untick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your save action is now part of your if: statement.  Drop it down an indent level so that it always ends the function

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.is_published:
       self.publish_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```